# Initialize double array java with enum value

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I have a little problem, I hope you can help me:

I have the class in java called TOKEN and it has this inside:

> ```
> public enum TOKEN { EMPTY, WHITE, BLACK }
> ```

In other class (same package) i'm trying to create a matrix of arrays with columns and rows, and i'm trying to initialize it with the value "EMPTY" from the other class "TOKEN":

```
public class Board {    
private int row;
private int column;
private TOKEN[][] board;

public Board(int nr, int nc){       
    this.row = nr;
    this.column = nc;
    for(int a=0; a < row; a++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b < column; b++)
          board[a][b] = TOKEN.EMPTY;
    }       
}
```

NR, and NC are ints and have values (for example 6,7) but when i try to run the code, it stops here (first iteration)

> board[a][b] = TOKEN.EMPTY;

Someone can help me please? Thank you!

Comment: stops? what happens exactly? any error messages you can provide?

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize the array first:

```
board = new TOKEN[nr][nc];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the `board` variable first using `new TOKEN[nr][nc]`:

```
public class Board {
    private final int row;
    private final int column;
    private final TOKEN[][] board;

    public Board(int nr, int nc) {
        this.row = nr;
        this.column = nc;
        // here we initialize the array, otherwise board will be null
        board = new TOKEN[nr][nc];
        for (int a = 0; a < row; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < column; b++) {
                board[a][b] = TOKEN.EMPTY;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board(10, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing initialization:

```
...
board = new TOKEN[row][column]; // <---
for(int a=0; a < row; a++)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor `Board` you need to initialize the array first, before you can fill it with empty Tokens:

```
public Board(int nr, int nc) {
    board = new TOKEN[nr][nc];    // initializes the matrix with nr arrays of nc size
    this.row = nr;
    this.column = nc;
    for (int a = 0; a < row; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < column; b++) {
            board[a][b] = TOKEN.EMPTY;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have withhold the error you get: a `NullPointerException`. And you get this exception because you simply forgot to initialize your array:

```
public Board(int nr, int nc){       
    this.row = nr;
    this.column = nc;
    this.board = new TOKEN[nr][nc]; // <-- here
    for(int a=0; a < row; a++) {
        for(int b=0; b < column; b++)
        board[a][b] = TOKEN.EMPTY;
    }       
}
```